# Compiling Issues For Java 7 In NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, compilation, java-7

So I have Java 7 (64bit Windows build 84) and NetBeans 6.8. I want to use the new `invokedynamic` stuff in Java 7 and compile from NetBeans but I can't figure out how to get NetBeans to run the program with the right options except when I build it (run fails, build works).

The code needs to be compiled with the option `-XDinvokedynamic` and run with `-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+EnableMethodHandles -XX:+EnableInvokeDynamic`. So, in the Project Properties dialogue, I change the Additional Compiler Options in Build to include `-XDinvokedynamic` but that only affects the build not when I click run.

I believe adding the `-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+EnableMethodHandles -XX:+EnableInvokeDynamic` options to the VM Options box in Run works correctly though (although I can't be sure).

So, simply how can I get NetBeans to use compile with `-XDinvokedynamic` whether I'm building or just running it?

Comment: you may want to ask questions like this on the nbusers@netbeans.org mailing list... use this page to subscribe: http://netbeans.org/community/lists/top.html

Comment: That sounds like a good idea! It looks like you've posted for me though (thanks!) but pasted the wrong link: http://forums.netbeans.org/topic23732.html

Comment: I think it has to do with setting `javac.compilerargs` but it seems NetBeans simply ignores this parameter.

Comment: did you use an ordninary netbeans project? and did you have multiple configurations specified for this project? What do you find as the javac.compilerargs and run.jvmargs in the file nbproject/project.properties ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NetBeans 6.8, the only way to get this to work is to turn off the Compile on Save option. When Compile on Save is on, the 'Additional Compiler Options' is ignored, silently.

There is a [bugzilla entry with more details about the effect of the compile on save property](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=181307).

Comment: That's suprisingly simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In each project's properties, in the compile part you can specify additional compile options like this one.

Comment: I've added my arguments to both the Additional Compiler Options (in Build -> Compiling) box and the Arguments box (in Run). But the arguments get ignored. Only running it at the command line works.